# 'super' and inheritance in Ruby

Tags: ruby, inheritance, super

In class inheritance design below, class `B` inherits class `A`, and valuates its methods' arguments:

```
class A
  def method_1(arg)
     puts "Using method_1 with argument value '#{arg}'"
  end

  def method_2(arg)
     method_1(arg)
  end
end

class B < A
   def method_1()
      super("foo")
   end

   def method_2()
      super("bar")
   end
end
```

Here's what I get when trying it:

```
inst_A = A.new
inst_A.method_1("foo")
# >> Using method_1 with argument value 'foo'
inst_A.method_2("bar")
# >> Using method_1 with argument value 'bar'
```

I no longer understand this:

```
inst_B = B.new
inst_B.method_1
# >> Using method_1 with argument value 'foo'
inst_B.method_2
# >> Error: #<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)>
# >> <main>:11:in `method_1'
# >> <main>:6:in `method_2'
# >> <main>:16:in `method_2'
```

Why is `B#method_1` called when invoking `B#method_2`, and not `A#method_1`?

Comment: I guess you are getting an error because Ruby doesn't support method overloading? When you Inheritance B < A, you are passing all the publics and protected methods to class B, as both have the same methods name, but different number of arguments, it seems to me that you are overloading the class B.

Comment: It's easier if you think in terms of message sending. `method_1(arg)` sends the message `method_1` to `self`, i.e. to `inst_B`. Ruby then searches for a method matching that name, starting with `B`'s methods and finds `B#method_1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modified your example to print out the current class in `A#method_1`

```
def method_1(arg)
   puts "Using method_1 from class: '#{self.class}' with argument value '#{arg}'"
end
```

If you call `B#method_1`, you'll get this output

```
Using method_1 from class: 'B' with argument value 'foo'
```

As you said, it's calling `B#method_1` (which overrides `A#method_1`). The same applies to when `B#method_2` calls `super`, and then that tries to call `self#method_1`, which takes no arguments. `self` in this case is of type `B`, and `B` overrode `method_1` to take no arguments.

Ruby first tries to find the method in `self` and calls it if it's found, otherwise it looks through that object's `ancestors` and calls the first version of the method it finds. In your case `self` has `method_1` which takes no arguments, and remember that Ruby doesn't support method overloading (unless you use optional parameters).

Comment: _"Remember that Ruby **doesn't** support method overloading (unless you use optional parameters)"_ nailed it for me. I naively assumed so, and that was the source of all my troubles. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`method_2` in class `B` calls `method_2`(super) in class `A` with the arg `"bar"`. `method_2` in class `A` (called from class `B`) calls `method_1` in class `B` with the arg `"bar"`. `method_1` and `method_2` from class `B` override their namesakes from class `A`. That is why `method_1` from the inheriting class gets called.

Comment: The OP is aware that `B#method_1` is called. The question is _why?_.